# Limit animate.css animations at only one time

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, animate.css, npm-package

I am using `animate.css` and `react-on-screen` npm packages, `react-on-screen` package is to use `TrackVisibility` component so I can make a nice fade-in effect. But I only want the animation to be done once. But every time when I scroll back to the component and it reappears on the screen the animation is retaken, and it's not such a great UI.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `visible` prop of the `TrackVisibility` component in conjunction with the `useState` hook, to keep track of whether the component has been animated or not. Once the component has been animated, you can use the `animated` prop to turn off the animation.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { TrackVisibility } from 'react-on-screen';

function MyComponent() {
  const [animated, setAnimated] = useState(false);

  return (
    <TrackVisibility onVisible={() => setAnimated(true)}>
      <div className={`my-component ${animated ? '' : 'animated fadeIn'}`}>
        <!-- ... -->
      </div>
    </TrackVisibility>
  );
}
```

In this example, the first time the `MyComponent` comes into view, the `animated` state variable is set to false, and the animation is applied. But when the `MyComponent` is scrolled out of view and then scrolled back into view, the `animated` state variable is already set to true, so the animation is not applied again.

It's also worth noting that if you want to make the animation only once you can use the `once` prop of the `TrackVisibility` component:

```js
<TrackVisibility once>
```